# How to upload to a webserver simple integer variable from android?

Tags: android, upload, webserver

How to upload to my webserver a simple integer variable from android?I want send the temperature variable.My server support php.Need permisions from webserver?I must create a temperature.php file with variable and upload it?

Comment: post your code what you have tried and if you are getting an error then also attach logcat with code

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that your server accepts POST request, take a look at this example of an HTTP POST request:

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);  
//you should put here your temp variable
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("temperature", String.valueOf(30)));

HttpPost request = post("http://mysite.com/temperature.php", nameValuePairs);

DefaultHttpClient client = generateHttpClient();
HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(request);
```

Where:

```
public static DefaultHttpClient generateHttpClient(){
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, TIMEOUT_CONNECTION);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, TIMEOUT_SOCKET);
        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));

        try{


KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        trustStore.load(null, null);

        SSLSocketFactory sf = new EasySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
        sf.setHostnameVerifier(
               SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

//      params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION,             HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    ClientConnectionManager cm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(cm, params);
    client.setKeepAliveStrategy(new ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy() { 
        @Override 
        public long getKeepAliveDuration(HttpResponse response, HttpContext 
    context) { 
            return 60; // seconds 
        } 

    }); 

    return client;

}
```

The missing class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
public class EasySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

        public EasySSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore)
                        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException,
                        KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
                super(truststore);



  TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                    String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    }

                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                    String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    }

                    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                            return null;
                    }
            };

            sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port,
                    boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
            return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port,
                            autoClose);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
            return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
    }
```

}

Comment: Yep, that would be the proper way =)

Comment: Ok.But i can't find the file where is the variables name,pass?

Comment: That's just an example of a basic login. I'm editing to show an example with your parameter.

Comment: I post the variables to the Url:mysite.com/temperature.php ?

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark my answer as correct if your problem was solved or to reply if there's something left ;)

Comment: Yep, you're just making a POST request, so any server that supports that method will be ok.

Comment: Updated, add that missing class.

Comment: Just add that class to your project and import it in the class in which you included the `generateHttpClient` method.

Comment: i have error post create method...Why you dont make a tutorial? I think is very good code...